# PHP file_get_contents does not assign the received html page content to the variable

Tags: php

PHP page does receive the output generated by the called html page. However, as it seems to process it asynchronously this data is not assigned to `$content`.

```
$content=file_get_contents('http://www.example1.com/xxx.html');   
echo strlen($content) . $content . strlen($content);
```

This coding initially echos the result of strlen($content1) twice:

```
1200
1200
```

Then a few seconds later the screen display changes as follows:

```
1200
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz1 ... 123 456 789
1200
```

(The html page output pops up between the already displayed strlen values).

The sad thing is that `$content` contains the html coding of the called page, instead of the expected `abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz1 ... 123 456 789` output generated by the html page.

The relevant part of the called html page www.example1.com/xxx.html looks like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>      
<script src="http://dexels.github.io/navajofeeds-json-parser/js/dist/feed-0.0.1.js"></script>       
<script>"feed.init({clientId: "AaBBawwErT"});</script>

<div data-article="schedule" data-param-a="YES" data-fields="aa,bb,cc,dd,ee"></div>
```

My html page seems to work perfectly as I get the correct result echoed on my screen. But how do I get this output to $content in my php page?

Tried adding `sleep(10)`, but this makes things worse as sleep seems to be processed in advance.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you saying that you want the raw html to appear on the screen? Or the result of executing that javascript once it's been loaded?

Comment: Thanks for your message. I want to receive the result of the called html page into the $content variable.

Comment: Unfortunately using cURL also shows the same symptom: the output file shows the html coding instead of the generated output ....                                                    <?php $ch = curl_init("http://www.example1.com/xxx.html"); $fp = fopen("output of html page.txt", "w"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); fclose($fp); ?>

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is is that the content you request from the server is html + javascript. But the actual data you want is generated by the JavaScript *in the browser*.

What you're *asking* to do is have PHP run that JavaScript. There's really not a good way of doing it that way without a *lot* of unnecessary work.

What you want to do instead is do the same thing the JavaScript is doing yourself.

If you use the Safari or Chrome Web Inspector when you load the url you included in your comment, you'll notice that a call is made to `data.sportslink.com` that returns a JSON object with all of the data the JavaScript renders.

You will have to generate that url and retrieve its data, and then `json_decode()` the result and do whatever necessary processing you need to do.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest how to implement the solution? Move the Javascript to php page but then couple the script to PHP? 

We noticed that the js code calls 'data.sportlink.com'. Probably it needs a ref to the data.specs specified in the DIV area plus the clientId specified the header area? How to accomplish? I added some PHP code but at least the url needs to be something else:
<?php $jsondata = file_get_contents('http://dexels.github.io/navajofeeds-json-parser/js/dist/feed-0.0.1.js');
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo ($obj['Result']);
echo "<pre>";
echo ($obj);
?>  Thank you!

Comment: The js file on dexels.github.io is the javascript code that's making the call to `data.sportlink.com`. Retrieving that code will do nothing for your php script; you need to actually implement in php *what that javascript is doing*.

Comment: Thank you. The javascript however contains 900 lines of code. Hard for me to investigate what's going there and then translate it's functionality to PHP. Can you suggest an approach?